# Implications of saving session on the client with javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD

Tags: security, jsf, session, viewstate, jsf-2.2

My first JSF page was throwing `javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException`. while I searched I got this solution which solved my problem.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But I am concerned about the security implication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't save the "session" in client side at all.

This only saves the JSF view state in client side. This is in JSF 2.2 always AES-encrypted with a key which is generated on application startup. This however invalidates once you restart the application, hereby causing all existing view states to become invalid. You can specify a fixed key as below in `web.xml` so that all existing view states keep valid across server restarts:

```
<env-entry>
    <env-entry-name>jsf/ClientSideSecretKey</env-entry-name>
    <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    <env-entry-value>[AES key in Base64 format]</env-entry-value>
</env-entry>
```

You can use [this page](http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/aes-key-generator.php) to generate a random AES key in Base64 format.

#### See also:

- [javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored)
- [com.sun.faces.ClientStateSavingPassword - recommendations for actual password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231372/com-sun-faces-clientstatesavingpassword-recommendations-for-actual-password/)
- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/) (read this to learn what "session" actually is)

Comment: I think there is a typo `jsf.ClientSideSecretKey` should be replaced by `jsf/ClientSideSecretKey`